# JQuery how to clear all the input:textfields of a .class on a form. Not working for me

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form, the first .class has 5 input:text boxes in it. I want to be able to clear all the text boxes with the click of a button. I've tried it a few ways and it's not working... here's what I've done.... (FYI, I have more classes in the form so I can't use .reset.

### The Form...

```
<table class="orderLine1 formFont" width="900">
 <tr>
    <td width="395">Product Name:<br><input class="ProductName" type="text" size="65"></td>
    <td width="97" class="formFontDisabled">Prod ID:<br><input class="Product_ID ffd" type="text" size="5" disabled></td>
    <td width="78" class="formFontDisabled">UPC:<br><input class="UPC ffd" type="text" size="13" disabled ></td>
    <td width="67" class="formFontDisabled">List Price:<br><input class="ListPrice ffd" type="text" size="7" disabled></td>    
    <td width="67">WholeSale:<br><input class="WholeSalePrice ffd" type="text" size="7" disabled></td>
    <td width="56">Quantity:<br><input class="qty addLine" type="text" size="7"></td>
    <td width="60" class="formFontDisabled">Line Total:<br><input class="subTotal ffd" type="text" size="10" disabled></td>
    <td width="44"><button class="OFDeleteButton">Delete</button><button class="OFClearLine" >OFClearLine</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### The Script Test # 1

```
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(function clearFirst() {
         $('.orderLine1').find(':input').each(function() {
             switch(this.type) {
                 case 'text':
                    $(this).val('');
                    break;
                 }
             });
        });

    $('.OFClearLine').click(function(e) {
        clearFirst();
    });
    });
```

### The Script Test # 2

```
  $(function(){
        $('.OFClearLine').bind('click', function(){
            $('.orderLine1').reset();
        });
    });
```

More info: OFClearLine is the class for the button I want to use & orderLine1 is the class of the form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.OFClearLine').click(function() {
    $('.orderLine1 input[type="text"]').val('');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```
$("input.className:text").val("");
```

Looking at your code, this might work better:

```
$(".className input[type='text']").val("");
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvUsD/1/

Comment: This one $(".className input[type='text']").val(""); didn't work for me, however this one $("input.className:text").val(""); worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code will find all the text inputs that are decendants of the `.orderLine1` table element and set their values to nothing.

```
$('.OFClearLine').bind('click', function(){
    $('.orderLine1').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.OFClearLine').click(function(e) {
        $('.orderLine1 input:text').each(function() {
                $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
```

You can see it in action on this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/nickyt/exWKL

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if it can see your clearFirst function. Also you can just use $('.orderLine1 input') to find all of the inputs in the .orderLine1 class.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {    
    $('.OFClearLine').click(function(e) {
        clearFirst();
    });
});

function clearFirst() {
    $('.orderLine1 input[type="text"]').each(function() {
         $(this).val('');
    });
}
```